# Want to write query selecting from a table based upon not appearing in another table

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: `player(playerId, Name)`, `game(gameId, gameName)`, and `gameResults(gameId, playerId, results)`.

I want to retrive the rows from `gameResults` where `gameId` does not exist in table `game`.

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     gameresults.playerId, 
     gameresults.results    
FROM 
     game, 
     gameresults, 
     player
WHERE
     gameresults.playerId = player.playerId
     AND gameresults.gameId NOT IN (
       SELECT game.gameId; FROM game
     )
```

also i tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     gameresults.playerId,
     gameresults.results    
FROM 
     game, 
     gameresults, 
     player
WHERE 
     gameresults.playerId = player.playerId
     AND gameresults.gameId NOT EXISTS(
          SELECT race.raceId, FROM race
     )
```

Comment: That won't be necessary as [gameResults.gameId] is a foreign key to [game.gameId]. The query will return zer... what? Oh, you didn't use RI?

Comment: @Ronnis: LOL. My bet is that he's trying to fix that now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT gameresults.playerId, gameresults.results, game.gameName
FROM gameresults
  LEFT JOIN game ON game.gameId = gameresults.gameId
/ * WHERE gameresults.gameName Is NULL <-- incorrect */
WHERE gameresults.gameId IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM gameResults 
WHERE gameId NOT IN (SELECT gameid FROM game)
```

quick and dirty but its easy to understand